# JavaFX printerPage(Layout, Node) does not print a TextFlow

Tags: javafx, printing, textflow

I am trying to print a formatted text.
Here is my code:

```
public class ProvaTextFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ProvaTextFlow p = new ProvaTextFlow() ;
        Node tf = p.creaTesto();
        p.stampa(tf);
    } 

    public Node creaTesto( )
    {
      String s1 = "Dear Mom," + "\n"
              +   " I am going out dancing tonight with :" + "\n\n\n"  ;

      String f1 = " (girl) friend 1" + "\n" +
                  "        friend 2" + "\n" +
                  " (girl) friend 3" + "\n\n\n\n"  ;

        String closing = "don't wait for me" + "\n\n\n\n"
                + "bye" + "\n\n" ;


      Text t1 = new Text (s1); 
      Text t2 = new Text (f1); 
      Text t3 = new Text (closing) ;

      t1.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
      t2.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 20));
      t3.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontPosture.ITALIC, 20));

      TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow() ; ;
        try {

            //Setting the width  
            textFlow.setPrefSize(2480, 3508); // 2480 X 3508 = A4(300)

            //Setting the line spacing  
            textFlow.setLineSpacing(5.0);

            //Retrieving the observable list of the TextFlow Pane 
            textFlow.getChildren().addAll(t1, t2, t3);

            // method to extract out of a TextFlow the String text.
            //             
            //////////////////////            
            //            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //            for (Node node : textFlow.getChildren()) 
            //            {
            //             if (node instanceof Text) 
            //             {
            //               sb.append(((Text) node).getText());
            //             }
            //            }
            //            String fullText = sb.toString();
            /////////////////////////            
            //            System.out.println("fulltext => " + fullText); 
        // this (when uncommented) correctly prints the unformatted text      } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return textFlow;
    }

    public void stampa (Node n2p)
    {
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter(); 

        javafx.print.PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout
                                            (
                                              Paper.A4, 
                                              PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 
                                              Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT
                                            ); 

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        boolean result = job.printPage(pageLayout, n2p);
        System.out.println(" print result => " + result);// this gives true

        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs corrrectly, `job.printPage()` returns `true`, the printer starts printing, but the A4 sheet is desperately blank.
Basically, I build a `TextFlow`, with three strings formatted each one in a different way, then I pass this (`TextFlow`) `Node` to the `Stampa` method.
If I print a `TableView`, no problems at all.
Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Look like you are missing some code? Is this a `JavaFX` program? If so, it seems you are missing the basic structure of the program.

Comment: This is part of a wider program. The GUI ( FX Application ) manages some info ( about pills I have to take ), then there is a method to format the text in order to print out a list. The same text could be used to be sent via email. So, yes, it is an FX Application, but this is only part of it.

Comment: In that case, how many `public static void main` does your program have?

Comment: This is only a side class, not a definitive one, to experiment with FX print facilities.If I put the TextFlow in a VBox, it is shown without problems, I have only one main method in my application, the GUI one. The printing logic  I am trying to implement will be located in the Print MenuItem of a File Menu, itself located in a Tabbed Pane. Moreover, I tested the 2 methods ( Createsto and Stampa ), inside the main application, and their behaviour is the same. So, I submitted the question with a code that anyone can play with, hoping to get the rigth answer.  Thanks.

Comment: You attempted to submit code anyone can play with.  The main you submitted is wrong for a JavaFX application.

Comment: Dear Sedrick, you are right. I removed the main() method from the ProvaTextFlow class, and I called its methods from within the FX Application. It is working now. Many thanks for your suggestions.